# Unexpected crash while clustering with RStudio on ec2 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, crash, rstudio, hclust

I am experiencing crashes with RStudio on the ec2 while clustering with currently 32 cores using the package doSNOW. The problem keeps happening and the logs in RStudio and the awslogs show following problems:

```
The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash. You may have lost workspace data as a result of this crash
```

I have tried a workaround found on the RStudio community page like this:

```
rm -rf ~/.rstudio
```

I restarted it, terminated the RStudio many times, but it didn't help. I change to a bigger instance: 
    r4.8xlarge
but the calculation couldn't be made either.

```
Apr 30 14:14:23 ip-172-31-46-102 rsession-rstudio[12984]: ERROR session hadabend; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error {anonymous}::rInit(const rstudio::r::session::RInitInfo&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:563
```

This is the following code when the RStudio crashes:

```
# Clustering using gower distance and hclust()
d <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) gower_dist(data[i,], data))
d <- as.dist(d)
h <- hclust(d)  # this causes error
```

Comment: The problem is solved - the hclust is not really suitable for big data. Replacing that by flashClust does not lead to a crash of RStudio anymore and the calculation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved - the hclust is not really suitable for big data. Replacing that by flashClust does not lead to a crash of RStudio anymore and the calculation was successful.